# How to display specific div that have image in webview

Tags: java, android

I've got the following

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://fajarpapua.com/2020/09/23/hasil-rapat-mulai-senin-aktifitas-warga-mimika-sampai-pukul-21-00-wit-ini-draft-aturan-baru-yang-wajib-dipatuhi/").get();
Elements divs = doc.select("div");
webViewAds.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   for (Element div : divs) {
        String html = div.getElementsByClass("majalahpro-core-banner-insidecontent").toString();
        String mime = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";
        webView.loadData(html, mime, encoding);
        }
```

i want to display this content on my webview,
[image]
but that's code doesn't work.
pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this piece of code:

```
 // Get all divs with classname you specified

Elements links = doc.select("div.majalahpro-core-banner-insidecontent");

                   //Loop over it
   
                    for (Element link : links) {
                     // Get its Html
                        String content = link.html();
                    }
```

Enjoy!